# Get image from remote sites and display smaller with PHP

Tags: php, html, image, curl, thumbnails

I'm looking for a way to get images from tweets.
I've been able to get tweets from users using oauth lib, etc.

Now, I have parsed each tweet and have to extract just the image from it. I'll use only yfrog, twitpic and lockerz.

I know yfrog.com image is named `main_image` inside a `<div class="the-image dont-hide">`

So, how can I get the image `src` from `main_image` `img` tag, resize it to 100x100, and display it, perhaps using gd.

Comment: If you want to resize in php then you have to retrieve the image. yFrog and twitpic (and I'd assume lockerz) provide APIs. Have you looked into them?

Comment: Yes, I've viewed them and yfrog is the easiest, because you can add :small to the url and get the thumbnail, but the others are not so easy so that's what I thought curl-crawling directly

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the APIs from each service to be able to get the source URL, I know for Yfrog and Lockerz it's possible, you just need to pass through the ID of the image, which should be part of the link in the original Tweet.

Once you have the URL, you could use TimThumb (http://www.darrenhoyt.com/2008/04/02/timthumb-php-script-released/) to resize the images, this will then cache the external image on your server.